# Pytorch model: drastically different inference results on different machines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I trained a segmentation model in Pytorch and tested it to give an F1-score of `0.93` on my local computer (Windows, conda, CUDA 10.2, Pytorch 1.2). However, the F1-score dropped to `0.3` when testing on a Linux server (conda, CUDA 9.0, Pytorch 1.1). I double checked that both sets of code, label files, test sets were the same, and there is no "explicit" random sampling in my code (even if so, the effect shouldn't be so drastic).

I tried the following to solve my problem:

I suspected that it might have something to do with Pytorch versions, so installed Pytorch 1.1 on my Windows machine to match the server's, but got the same `0.93` score. I then thought it had to do with CUDA itself, so eliminated the GPU factor altogether and did inference on cpu on server, I still got `0.3` on server.

What could possibly be causing this huge discrepancy?

Comment: Are the floating point precisions determined automatically in your code?  Could it possibly be due to an issue with 16 vs 32 vs 64 bit floats?

Comment: Possibly! Still checking but calling `double` doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Forgot to post an update, both versions evaluate float32 tensors

Comment: Add a lot of assertions that the data loader is yielding expected values. Assume that Linux/Windows yield different results for reading files. Which is a common issue, and then work your way from there. I wouldn't even look at PyTorch/Cuda until I verify my data was correct.

Comment: Just verified that the data is loaded properly. The problem seems to be that my network is outputting different mask predictions on 2 different machines... I'll test it out on a 3rd.

Comment: Not working (~0.3 F1 score) on 3rd machine/2nd Linux server either..

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm running into something somewhat similar.

Comment: Training a NN doesn't always go as planned. Neuron initialization has a lot to do with the outcome of the training. Could you double check that your gradients are what you expect them to be? If you would show us plots of losses (val,train), F1 score, mAP, gradients. Which model are we talking about? yolov5-seg?